# C++ Passing multiple files using * character via command line

Tags: c++, linux, windows, powershell, argv

Under linux, I do the following

> > COMMAND /home/directory/*.txt

and all the files in that directory get passed as separate parameters (20 files in the directory results in 20 parameters in the argv variable)

Under windows, the same command results in one parameter (that string exactly).

Is this a compiler issue (VisualC++ 2008) or a windows thing or what?

In the past, I've written batch files to parse the files into multiple parameters, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:c++] or [tag:argv], that's a `shell` feature!

Comment: Figured it was related to the shell, but wondering if there's a way to force it to behave in a similar way on windows as it does on linux.

Comment: You might consider using the [MSys bash](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) on windows for instance, that should provide this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat more limited than most Unix shells, but VC++ includes a file named `setargv.obj` that you can link with to add globbing to your application. It supports `*` and `?`, which covers most of what most people care about.

To use it, just include `setargv.obj` when you link your file. In most cases, this just means adding the file name to the command line, something like this:

```
cl myfile.c myotherfile.c setargv.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that is a shell globbing feature.  In PowerShell you would handle wildcard expansion inside your function using `Convert-Path` (or Resolve-Path) e.g.:

```
function ITakeWildcards([string]$Path) {
    $paths = Convert-Path $path
    foreach ($aPath in $paths) {
        "Processing path $aPath"
    }
}
```

Comment: No, not as nice as shell globbing.  But then again, seems that various forms of Linux have a shell globbing security vulnerability.  But I didn't expect anything else from a 
Linux shell.  :-)

Comment: Heheh.  I used Korn shell for many years and liked it much better than Windows CMD/Batch files.  But PowerShell has a lot to like.  Sometimes it feels like a "many headed beast" with a big surface area to learn but I've enjoyed it and it has certainly helped me be more productive in my job.

Comment: I'm kinda jealous of the object pipeline, but I balance that out by not having the awful console renderer that is w32/cmd.exe ;)

Comment: That is definitely a downside but the PSReadline module on GitHub at least makes the line editing experience quite a bit better.  https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine